# What is the probability $|R_1|, |R_2| \leq 1$ given $R_1, R_2$ real?

Tags: probability

Consider the quadratic $x^2+2Vx+U=0$, where U, V are independent uniform r.v.s on [0, 1]. Let  $R_1, R_2$ be the roots of the quadratic. What is the probability that $|R_1|, |R_2| \leq 1$ given $R_1, R_2$ real?.

The probability they are real is $\frac{1}{3}$, since we want $P(V^2>U)$. I am struggling to formulate the conditional probability.

Answer (score 1):

Under condition $U\leq V^2$ the roots are $-V+\sqrt{V^{2}-U}$ and $-V-\sqrt{V^{2}-U}$.

Observe that $\left|-V+\sqrt{V^{2}-U}\right|\leq1$ follows directly
from $V\in\left[0,1\right]$ and $0\leq U\leq V^{2}$.

Observe that $\left|-V-\sqrt{V^{2}-U}\right|\leq1\iff V+\sqrt{V^{2}-U}\leq1$.

So to be found is: $$P\left(V+\sqrt{V^{2}-U}\leq1\mid U\leq V^{2}\right)$$

Comment: Which is the equivalent of $P(2V+1 \leq U|U \leq V^2)$ = $\frac{P(2V+1 \leq U \cap U \leq V^2)}{P(U \leq V^2)}$. Do you get $\frac{1}{4}$ as your final answer?

Comment: I have no final answer (too lazy for that :-)) but only *formulated* the conditional probability. That was the problem you stated, right? Maybe later but I make no promises.

Comment: I think it should be $P(2V-1\leq U\mid U\leq V^2)$:$$V+\sqrt{V^{2}-U}\leq1\iff\sqrt{V^{2}-U}\leq1-V\iff V^{2}-U\leq1-2V+V^{2}\iff-U\leq1-2V\iff2V-1\leq U$$